# Create a single value for all vector values in property panel

Tags: geometry-nodes, geometry

I'd like to know how to create a single value for a vector that I can expose in the property panel as a user input.

For example, I connect a value node to a vector.  I control the three vectors with that one value node.  Now I'd like to expose that in the property panel and have a user adjust a single property there instead of going through the node graph.

I'd love to add an image to help clarify, but gives me an error.  That's another post I guess :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drag the vector you want to expose to the empty socket of the *Group Input* node. This makes a vector input of it. Then go to the properties of the node and change the socket *Type* to *Float*.

[image: vector to float]

Comment: I had the hardest time getting this to work.  I wasn't changing its type.  Thank you so much Gordon!!